# Viewing / Retrieving Attributes

Tags: c#, reflection

Inside a class, I have the following piece of code:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Errors", typeof(ErrorsType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Success", typeof(SuccessType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Warnings", typeof(WarningsType))]
public object[] Items {
    get {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
```

Using just reflection, is it possible to retrieve these attributes?
I saw '`GetCustomAttributes()` on the respective `Type`, but didnt get much joy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to retrieve the attributes from the property, not the type itself, like so:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Items").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlElementAttribute), false);
```

Or more complete (remember to import System.Linq for Cast<> and ToArray() to work):

```
XmlElementAttribute[] attribs = typeof(TheType)
                  .GetProperty("Items")
                  .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlElementAttribute), false)
                  .Cast<XmlElementAttribute>()
                  .ToArray();
```